# Why does a tcp remoting client needs to listen?

Tags: .net, tcp, remoting

When a remoting client creates a TcpClientChannel object, it listens on an (unspecified) port. What for?

A single tcp connection to the server is already a full duplex, so why listen?

Answer (score 1):

The client of the TCP connection has to listen on the source port of the connection, to receive packets transmitted from the server to the client. There are two ports involved in a TCP connection, a source and a destination port. Usually only the destination port is specified, and the source port is just assigned by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it listens for incoming connections. What's full-duplex have to do with it?

Comment: Why would a client listen for incoming connections?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the [MSDN TcpClientChannel Class example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpclientchannel.aspx) and the ServerChannel close by. There is no reference to listening clients. Please elaborate your case.

Another .NET CodeGuru article describes [simple remoting](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c10199/) and [secure remoting](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c10253__1/).
You can use this to elaborate your point.